# why jaxb converts the elements in <choice> with one variable connected with Or?

Tags: jaxb

This has been puzzling me, that is if I have a schema like the following,

```
    <xs:element name="api">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element ref="a" minOccurs="1" />
          <xs:element ref="b" minOccurs="1" />
          <xs:element ref="c" minOccurs="1" />
```

CASE1: When it is like

```
    <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
```

JAXB "xjc -p SomePackageName -d . ...." would generate a variable in Api.java such as

```
    protected List<Object> aOrBOrC;
```

CASE2: However, if I change it to

```
    <xs:choice maxOccurs="1">
```

JAXB generates

```
    protected A a;
    protected B b;
    protected C c;
```

My question is in CASE1, how do I retrieve the value of A, B, and C individually since it is only given ONE variable although its a list of them.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is done to preserve the order when you marshal the objects back to XML.

A document like the following is valid according to your XML Schema (due to the `maxOccurs="unbounded"` on the choice and it couldn't be represent by more than one property.

```
<api>
    <b/>
    <b/>
    <c/>
    <a/>
    <b/>
    <c/>
</api>
```

Comment: Thanks but say my xml does have an instance/value of "a", "b" and "c", how do I retrieve the content of each one of them if it Only has ONE variable AOrBorC?

Comment: @user2167013 - Based on your XML Schema you are either going to be able to tell this by: 1) The type of object (I.e instance of `Foo` means the element was `b`. 2) If the property type is `List<JAXBElement>` you can tell from the `QName` property on `JAXBElement`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23779674/marshalling-with-xsd-choice-field-in-class/23791067#23791067

Comment: Thanks, so if a, b, and c coexist, we can't retrieve all of them since only one variable is given. Is it a bug in JAXB? Sorry for being dumb, I just can't seem to understand why <choice> would create ONE variable only, again I give minOccurs="1" to all 3 element.

Comment: @user2167013 - Can you update your question with the corresponding property that gets generated?

Comment: I have rephrased my original question above. Hope someone has an answer. tx

Comment: @user2167013 - Can you also include the annotation that is on that property?